# Print on client using WinForm or application

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, wcf

I have developed ASP.NET program. The problem is: I want to select the printer on client and print it.

I know it is almost impossible, maybe with ActiveX, but I don't know much about ActiveX and it only works under IE.

So I created a workaround. I created a WinForm that runs on PC client and connect to my ASP.NET via WCF.

Until now works fine, but the process become annoying for the client. Because he has to work on ASP.NET to save the item and run the Winform and click it to retrive the item from ASP.NET and print it.

Nowadays I use the PULL method, that's meant that my Winform PULL the data from ASP.NET.
I wonder if I can use the PUSH method, that meant the ASP.NET push the data to Winform and the client only clicks in one button on ASP.NET.
Or how can I make my winform always listen into ASP.NET?

By the way, I want to simplify the client-side, so he only clicks one button instead of two.

Thank you in advance,
Stev

Comment: Why can't the user use their print button in the browser?

Comment: i did,  but it cost 2 clic (1 clic save item and 2 clic dialog print)

Comment: Can you elaborate on "cost 2 clic"?  Costs time, money, what?  For user time, launching another app is far worse.  For money, you shouldn't get charged for interacting with a local print dialog.

I was going to answer the same as Joshua Drake's 3rd suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

As I see it you could:

1. Remake your WinForms application as a WCF service hosted in a Windows service running on the client.  That would enable your ASP.NET page to call the WCF service and tell it to print.
2. Add a web browser control to your WinForms app and do everything form inside a single application.
3. Generate the information you want to print on the ASP.NET server side, say as a PDF, and then let the user print it normally. Similar to @AdamKing.